# Parse string date to date in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation

i am fetching date from excel sheet and set into the textbox. my original date is 01/01/2010 but when i am fetching from excel and print into java file it show date like "40179" in selenium webdriver. how to parse this value original date format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your date cell format in excel to "Text". Then try to fetch date. It will work for sure.

Also get date like : **Date dt=sheet.getRow(1).getCell(1).getDateCellValue();**